# How to get windows username php on 000webhost.com

Tags: php

I am trying to get the windwos username by using getenv

```
echo " USERNAME ".getenv("username");
```

works fine on localhost but not on 000webhost.com
also if I `global $_ENV; var_dump($_ENV);
$_ENV = array(0){}`

Maybe somebody knows how to get the username in a different way, or maybe has a solution to get `getenv()` to work on 000webhost 
ty in advance

Comment: Is your hosted server Windows or Linux

Comment: `000webhost` is blocking a lot of functions because people did exploit these functions.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Linux server

Comment: Can you describe more about your use case? Do you want to get the username of the user that runs your web server (i.e. IIS / Apache / Nginx)? Or do you want to learn the username of the website visitor?

Comment: @KoalaYeung username of the visitor

Comment: @AndroidAmateur99: Website visitor access your program through browser (i.e. IE, Firefox, Chrome). I think none of them would expose their Windows username to any external program. Your localhost works only because your local web server solution provides the username of who running it. Not the visitor's Windows username.

Comment: Then that probably does not have a `username` environment variable

Comment: I think you need to think of alternative way to get the visitor's name. (e.g. Let them will in themselves. Let them provide their name and email with Facebook OAuth2-based API.)